# What are important things to look for when choosing firmware?

Tags: device-firmware

I just got a Pandigital eReader and I'm browsing the firmware options(official and hacks).  What are important things to look for when choosing firmware?  Is there anything important to look for?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

1. Stability
2. Battery life

You should be able to get an idea from reviews/comments/etc. about how well each ROM performs in those areas.  For an eReader that's really all you need.